# Can I get the Content-Type from an S3 object stream without making an explicit call to headObject?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am streaming files from S3 and through my API to the client in order to enforce access control rules. In doing so, I need to set the content-type header appropriately. Does anyone know of a way to get the content-type from S3 without making a separate call to headObject? Right now I have to first get the object metadata and then make another request to get the object stream.

EDIT:
To clarify, I'm using

```
return s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
```

to get the stream, so there is no callback that I'm aware of.

Comment: A `GET` request returns exactly the same metadata in the headers that you get from a `HEAD` request... so it seems like you already should have what you are looking for, in data.ContentType in the callback from getObject. Wouldn't you?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782434/streaming-file-from-s3-with-express-including-information-on-length-and-filetype?rq=1

Comment: you can get the content type from the data returned by the getObject method:
here's an example from the official documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property:~:text=To%20retrieve%20a%20byte%20range%20of%20an%20object

Answer (score -6):

S3 will save the object with `Content-Type` that you specify while save your data by calling the `putObject` function.

```
s3Instance.putObject({
  Bucket: "my-bucket",
  ContentType: "application/xml",
  Body: xmlContent
}, function(err) {
  //callback here
});
```

**Source**: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

The `Content-Type` of the return object while calling the `getObject` function will be the same that you specify above. However you can set the `Content-Type` that you desire while calling the `getObject` function:

```
s3Instance.getObject({
  Bucket: "my-bucket",
  Key: "MyXMLFile",
  ContentType: "text/xml"
}, function(err, data) {
  //callback here
});
```

**Source**: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, of how to access the content type header when using the `s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()` pattern.

Comment: It returns `Unexpected key 'ContentType'`

Comment: this doesnt work